# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar node js en un servidor centos 8?

Tags: nodejs, express, npm, proxy

Tengo una aplicación REST en Node js. En las pruebas de desarrollo especifico el puerto 3000, hago la petición http://dominio.mx:3000/ y se ejecuta normalmente, pero para pasar a producción debo omitir el puerto para que sea una url y no ejecuta la aplicación.

Archivo server.js

```
'use strict';

const { config, express, database, log, stats } = require('./config');
const routes = require('../routes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const http = require('http');
let server = null;

/**
 * Start HTTP/2 server, database
 * Load routes, services, check memory usage
 * @function
 */
const listen = () => {
    const app = express.init();
    database.init();
    server = http.createServer(app).listen(config.port);
    routes.init(app);
    stats.memory();
    log.info(`  Escuchando en ${config.url}`);
};

/**
 * Close server, database connection
 * @function
 */
const close = () => {
    server.close();
    mongoose.disconnect();
    log.info('Server is offline. Bye!');
};

module.exports = {
    listen,
    close
};
```

Voy a usar un servidor dedicado centos 8, éste ya tiene instalado nodejs y npm, con éstos paquetes node corre sin problema especificando el puerto.
Al desplegar la aplicación en Heroku funciona correctamente, pero en el servidor centos, no.

Voy comenzando a desarrollar con esta tecnología y a la vez desplegando la API en un servidor dedicado, ¿será problema del lado de infraestructura o debo hacer algunas configuraciones a mi archivo server.js?

Comment: Normalmente un servidor Node se usa detrás de un [proxy inverso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_proxy#Proxy_inverso_(Reverse_Proxy)). Supongo que tu servidor web es Apache, Nginx o algún otro tipo de servidor web popular. Pues lo usual es levantar tu servidor Node en el equipo que corre tu servidor web y configurar una ruta (`/api` es la más usual), para que toda petición a esta ruta sea enviada mediante el proxy inverso hacia tu servidor Node. Es lo que hace `heroku` por ejemplo.

Comment: Otra configuración es aquella en la que el Servidor Web está en un equipo diferente al Servidor Node, igualmente se configura el proxy inverso para que toda petición a tu API sea redirigida internamente hacia tu servidor Node. Todo dependerá de la configuración de tu Servidor Web. Saludos

Comment: Por último, si vas usar el servidor de Node como solución web para tu aplicación, entonces debes tomar en cuenta que el puerto `http` por defecto es el 80, por lo tanto tu servidor debería escuchar en dicho puerto y no en el puerto 3000. Pero, toma en cuenta que estás levantando un servidor `http` el cual no se considera seguro, y deberías reemplazarlo por un servidor `https`. Eso implica instalar un certificado y cambiar algunas cosas en tu código. Por norma general, **yo**, no expongo un servidor Node directamente a Internet, sino que lo configuro mediante proxy inverso. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, @MauricioContreras, me has ayudado bastante aclarando mis dudas, haré las configuraciones pertinentes y por agradecimiento te cuento cuando haya sido exitoso mi despliegue.

Comment: La solución fue configurar un reverse proxy en el servidor web Apache